# how to display charts onclick on marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, leaflet

how to display canvas.js charts on click on marker .and so that charts should be displayed in modal box in the bottom on same page.
my code is:

```
var map = L.map( 'map', {
    center: [27.0238,74.2179],
    minZoom: 6,
    zoom: 2
});
L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    subdomains: ['a','b','c']
}).addTo( map );



var myURL = jQuery( 'script[src$="leaf-demo.js"]' ).attr( 'src' ).replace( 'leaf-demo.js', '' );
 var mywms = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8880/geoserver/march_demo/wms", {
    layers: 'march_demo:dist_reproject',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    version: '1.1.0',
    attribution: "myattribution"
});
mywms.addTo(map);
var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: myURL + 'images/mark.png',
    iconSize: [24, 22],
    iconAnchor: [9, 21],
    popupAnchor: [0, -14]
});

for ( var i=0; i < markers.length; i++ ) 
{
   L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng], {icon: myIcon} )
      .bindPopup( '<a href="' + markers[i].url + '" target="_blank">' + markers[i].name + '</a>' )
      .addTo( map );
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anushri21/hoja92nn/

Comment: What is your problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: on click on marker i am getting url and on clicking it charts open in next page . i want it should display on bottom of the map as modal box or on click as popup

Comment: You probably need a library (jQueryUI has a function "Dialog", for example) or come up with something yourself